# Issue starting windows phone emulator

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

Windows OS 10

Windows Phone emulator is unable to verify that the machine is running. I Also experience this issue when running android simulators through Visual Studio

Error:
[image: http://puu.sh/rYSHI/1f87937cb1.png]

> Error for running android: Could not launch "VS Emulator 7" Kitkat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet device. Exit code 10.

WIndows phone

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: App1.WinPhone, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
> 1>DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device 'FC3E1944-4E66-4A17-A9AF-663C294610C6'.':
> 1>ObjectDisposedException - 0x80131622

Hyperv Services:
[image: http://puu.sh/rYRYX/c831a61c36.png]

> Coreinfo.exe -v
>
> "HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
>
> VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
>
> EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)"

I have tried the following things

- Disable/Enable virtualization in the bios
- Repairing windows phone 8.1 SDK
- Enabling/Disabling HyperV
- Disabling antivirus
- Restarting PC(Sadly no fix :( )
- Deleted all VM's
- Recreating "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"

Comment: And what does the Hyper-V Manager show and tell? I can start that image even in the normal  Hyper-V console, without VS.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is what happens when I start an emulator in hyper-V Manager http://puu.sh/rYULi/6af7576d3f.png

Comment: which Win10 version? 1511 or 1607?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Microsoft Windows 10  Pro V10.0.10586 build 10586

Comment: try to update to version 1607 and install the VS2015 update 3 with 14393 SDK and WP8.1 Emulator. Now try to start the emulator

Comment: @magicandre1981 no luck

Comment: run **BCDEDIT /Set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto** from a cmd, satrted as admin to enable start of hyper-v. reboot look if this helps

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing the following commands fixed it. Thank

> net localgroup administrators LOCAL /delete
>
> net localgroup administrators SERVICE /delete

From http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a-18.html#post487916

Comment: ok, I never saw this before, but nice to hear that you were able to fix it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, guess it was some weird permission issue.